# How to create a dictionary with reocurring values for keys?

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tuples

I have this list of pets:

```
pets = [("Fido", "John", "Malkovic", 22),
    ("Butch", "Jake", "Smirnoff", 18),
    ("Zooma", "Simon", "Ng", 32),
    ("Chase", "Martha", "Black", 73),
    ("Rocky", "Simon", "Ng", 32)]
```

I need to create a function which takes a list structured like that and gives a dictionary where name,surname and age are used as a key and a dog's name is a value. For this particular list the answer is

```
{("John", "Malkovic", 22): ["Fido"],
 ("Jake", "Smirnoff", 18): ["Butch"],
 ("Simon", "Ng", 32): ["Zooma", "Rocky"],
 ("Martha", "Black", 73): ["Chase"]
}
```

what I tried to do is to create a list of keys, create a list of values and then try to somehow put them in a dictionary

```
q=[]
for i in pets:
    q.append(tuple(i[-3:]))
```

this step gives me a  list of keys:

```
[('John', 'Malkovic', 22), ('Jake', 'Smirnoff', 18), ('Simon', 'Ng', 32), ('Martha', 'Black', 73), ('Simon', 'Ng', 32)]
```

then I create a list of values:

```
b=[]
for i in pets:
    b.append(i[0])
```

it gives me this list:

```
['Fido', 'Butch', 'Zooma', 'Chase', 'Rocky']
```

and then I try to populate a dictionary using these two lists:

```
d=dict(zip(q,b))
```

but I dont get what I need:

```
{('John', 'Malkovic', 22): 'Fido', ('Jake', 'Smirnoff', 18): 'Butch', ('Simon', 'Ng', 32): 'Rocky', ('Martha', 'Black', 73): 'Chase'}
```

Firstly, this method doesnt allow me to put two values for one key(in this case I have to pair values "Zooma" and "Rocky" with key "("Simon", "Ng", 32)") and secondly, it skips a value if list which contains keys has two similar keys(in this case it has two instances of ("Simon", "Ng", 32) )
How do i create such a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do this:

```
d = dict(zip(q,b))
```

What happens is that `q` and `b` are paired up and then each entry is treated as a key/value pair for the dictionary. If `q` has duplicate entries, that means the same key will be set twice and its value overwritten (not skipped).

You want your values to be lists of values, but the command above would set them as direct values (note from your own example that the pets aren't in lists).

One solution that follows your logic until the last step is to use a `defaultdict` of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# ...

d = defaultdict(list)
for person, pet in zip(q, b):
    d[person].append(pet)
```

The `defaultdict` avoids having to create a new list for each value and creates an empty list to add to for each new key, while just adding to the list of existing keys.

However, a simpler approach would be to just create the dictionary in one go:

```
from collections import defaultdict

pets = [("Fido", "John", "Malkovic", 22),
    ("Butch", "Jake", "Smirnoff", 18),
    ("Zooma", "Simon", "Ng", 32),
    ("Chase", "Martha", "Black", 73),
    ("Rocky", "Simon", "Ng", 32)]


d = defaultdict(list)
for pet, first, last, age in pets:
    d[(first, last, age)].append(pet)
```

Or, if you really don't want the `defaultdict`:

```
d = {}
for pet, first, last, age in pets:
    key = (first, last, age)
    if key not in d:
        d[key] = []
    d[key].append(pet)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `defaultdict(list)` -- this automagically creates a new list when the owner is not a key of the dictionary and appends to it if they already are a key:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for row in pets:
    d[row[1:]].append(row[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped

Answer (score 0):

```
pets = [("Fido", "John", "Malkovic", 22),
    ("Butch", "Jake", "Smirnoff", 18),
    ("Zooma", "Simon", "Ng", 32),
    ("Chase", "Martha", "Black", 73),
    ("Rocky", "Simon", "Ng", 32)]

data = [{item[-3:]: list(item[:1])} for item in pets]

res = dict()
for dict in data:
   for list in dict:
      if list in res:
         res[list] += (dict[list])
      else:
         res[list] = dict[list]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
{('John', 'Malkovic', 22): ['Fido'], ('Jake', 'Smirnoff', 18): ['Butch'], ('Simon', 'Ng', 32): ['Zooma', 'Rocky'], ('Martha', 'Black', 73): ['Chase']}
```